# capture list of strings from the value of key-value pair in a json output | VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, json.net, http-post

I have a valid POST-request response converted to json via

```
Dim jsonResulttodict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, object))(responseFromServer)
```

While parsing the dictionary, two level inside I find a 'list' of strings as below

```
Dim levelOne = jsonResulttodict.item ("level_one")
Dim levelTwo = levelOne.item ("level_two")
```

On mouse-hover, `levelTwo` shows up as:

```
{["value-3", "value-2", "value-1"]}
```

and `Console.Writeline(levelTwo.ToString())` results in:

```
[ "value-3", "value-2", "value-1" ]
```

It sounds silly but I'm simply unable to capture this into a variable (a list of strings).

I've already tried these, but neither works:

```
Dim mylist As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)({levelOne.item("level_two")})
```

and

```
For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of String)) In levelTwo
            Console.WriteLine(pair.Key)
            Console.Write("  ")
            Console.WriteLine(pair.Value)
        Next
```

Comment: `Object` is generally too generic/basic to do much with.  If you cant/wont/dont know how to use a class, try `Dictionary(Of String, String())`

Comment: I thought so too.But it turns out it's a JObject (as in Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject).

Comment: If it is J-Anythying *afterwards* something is still not quite right.  It cannot have started life as a JArray, JObject or JAnythingElse.  Your post starts in the middle of the process such that we never see the starting data

Comment: You're right. It didn't start as a JArray/JObject. The JObject got created when I do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` the string response from the POST request. But, the starting data is the string `responseFromServer` as mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further inspection, I printed out the type of the variable.

```
Console.WriteLine(levelTwo.GetType())
```

I got it as `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray`. Which now makes everything seem so trivial.
I'm now able to iterate over the JArray as follows

```
for each value as String In levelTwo
    Console.WriteLine(value.ToString())
Next
```

Prints as follows:

```
value-3
value-2
value-1
```